# Changing code-insiders terminal command to something smaller

Tags: bash, visual-studio, terminal, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code insiders version and am tired of typing `code-insiders` to prompt it from the terminal. How can I replace it with something smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set bash alias for it. Just go to `.bashrc` file in your `$HOME` directory and add the following new line:

```
alias something-smaller='code-insiders'
```